# Changeable Schema for a Specific Entity with JPA and Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring and JPA repositories, with multiple database schemas for different entities, and configuring each of them with the proper values and independent beans:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {ClassFromSchemaXRepository.class}, entityManagerFactoryRef = "ClassFromSchemaXEntityManagerFactoryA", transactionManagerRef = "ClassFromSchemaXTransactionManager")
{
    @Bean
    public DataSource classFromSchemaXDataSource(){
       HikariDataSource hds = new HikariDataSource();
       hds.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("dataSource.jdbcUrl.schema.x"));
       hds.setUsername(env.getProperty("dataSource.user"));
       hds.setPassword(env.getProperty("dataSource.password"));
        //...
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean classFromSchemaXEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(classFromSchemaXDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.company.core.domain.x" });
        //...
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager classFromSchemaXTransactionManager() {
        //...
    }

}
```

This configuration works as expected, and the entire set of entities which are located under the **'com.company.core.domain.x'** package is mapped to this sets of beans with the schema connection string which is defined in **env.getProperty("dataSource.jdbcUrl.schema.x")**

However, I am now trying to configure *a specific entity* to be used by *changeable schema* and therefor dymanic DataSource/EntityManagerFactory/TransactionManager. 
The business logic should determine which schema should be used at runtime.

What is the best method of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I've found what I was looking for which is extending the **AbstractRoutingDataSource** class, and overriding the *determineCurrentLookupKey*() method